# SharePoint 2013 - Send-to button greyed out - probably because of claims?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I wonder if someone knows...
We have installed SharePoint 2013, and we realized that the send-to button in document libraries is greyed out. When we created a new web application with NTLM authentization, the button was not greyed out. Therefore, we suppose that claims authentization does this. Does anyone know why, or how to solve this without coding? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the behavior of NTLM vs Claims different with web apps on the same server or different servers?